# Kafka - Simple consumer/producer setup doesn't work on different machines, but works locally

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I've installed and setup `Kafka` using the following simple `producer`/`consumer` tutorial:

https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

I have **two machines**, and both are using `Ubuntu`.

**Resume of the problem:**

If I use the `producer` and `consumer` on the same machine, everything works fine. 
If I use the `producer` on `machine 2`, and the rest on `machine 1`, such as `kafka`, `zookeeper` server and the `consumer`, I never receive any messages on `machine 1`.

```
Machine 1 has IP: 192.168.1.100

Machine 2 has IP: 192.168.1.101
```

> Working Example using just the Machine 1 only, with 4 console
>   applications

**Console 1** - started zookeeper:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

**Console 2** - started kafka server

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

**Console 3**
Created a topic called test:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

Tested the topic:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

Started the consumer

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test
```

**Console 4** - Send some messages:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
```

It works!

> **NOT** Working Example using Machine 1 and 2

**Machine 1 - Console 1** - started zookeeper:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

**Machine 1 - Console 2** - started kafka server

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

**Machine 1 - Console 3**
Created a topic called test:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper 192.168.1.100:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

Tested the topic:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper 192.168.1.100:2181
```

Started the consumer

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 192.168.1.100:9092 --topic test
```

**Machine 2 - Console 1** - Send some messages to kafka on the IP 192.168.1.100

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 192.168.1.100:9092 --topic test
```

Doesn't work ...

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**

I've used now the kafkacat to test the connection...here is the output.

```
root@ubuntu:~/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1# kafkacat -b 192.168.1.100 -t test -L
Metadata for test (from broker -1: 192.168.1.100:9092/bootstrap):
 1 brokers:
  broker 0 at ubuntu:9092
 1 topics:
  topic "test" with 1 partitions:
    partition 0, leader 0, replicas: 0, isrs: 0
%3|1507802180.807|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:ubuntu:9092/0]: ubuntu:9092/0: Connect to ipv4#127.0.1.1:9092 failed: Connection refused
%3|1507802180.807|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:ubuntu:9092/0]: ubuntu:9092/0: Connect to ipv4#127.0.1.1:9092 failed: Connection refused
```

Why is the `127.0.1.1:9092` set above?
Shouldn't be `192.168.1.100:9092`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Whycan%27tmyconsumers/producersconnecttothebrokers?), a common problem is the hostname:

> When a broker starts up, it registers its ip/port in ZK. You need to make sure the registered ip is consistent with what's listed in `metadata.broker.list` in the producer config. By default, the registered ip is given by `InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostAddress()`. Typically, this should return the real ip of the host. However, sometimes (e.g., in EC2), the returned ip is an internal one and can't be connected to from outside. The solution is to explicitly set the host ip to be registered in ZK by setting the `hostname` property in `server.properties`. In another rare case where the binding host/port is different from the host/port for client connection, you can set `advertised.host.name` and `advertised.port` for client connection.

So, open your `server.properties` and change the `hostname`:

```
host.name=<your hostname>
```

If this still doesn't work, try to modify the `advertised.host.name`:

```
advertised.host.name=<your ip>
```

If this really does not work, have a look at the `advertised.listeners` and ensure it is either `0.0.0.0:port` or `<your.ip>:port`. Example:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
```

Comment: Thank you Derlin. I've set all that on the client side, by setting the IP/Port of the server side (where the zookeeper, kafka server, and the consumer is based). But it didn't work. However, if I run the script that dumps all the topics from the server, I see those correctly. The only thing that doesn't work, is sending a message from the producer to the consumer(server). any thoughts?

Comment: This is the command I want to use: bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 192.168.1.100:9092 --topic test

Comment: [2017-10-11 16:02:26,234] WARN Connection to node 0 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Comment: if you really set all the properties above, try restarting your kafka (using `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`) and zookeeper and ensure the topic exists.

Comment: still doesn't work. Can you check my edit, please? I've added a new test.

Comment: is the version of kafka-server running in node 1 and producer running in node 2 to be consistent?

Comment: answer from here helped. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086884/not-able-consume-messages-from-remote-machine-in-kafka