# Unable to access kafka from outside Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I have a confluent kafka setup and `docker-compose.yml` file

https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.0.0-post/examples/kafka-cluster/docker-compose.yml

I have edited the file and added the `ports` option to the docker compose file so that I can access them outside of the host.

```
---
version: '2' 
services: 
  zookeeper-1: 
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest 
    environment: 
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1 
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22181 
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000 
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5 
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2 
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: localhost:22888:23888;localhost:32888:33888;localhost:42888:43888 
    network_mode: "host" 

  zookeeper-2: 
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest 
    environment: 
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2 
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181 
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000 
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5 
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2 
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: localhost:22888:23888;localhost:32888:33888;localhost:42888:43888 
    network_mode: "host" 

  zookeeper-3: 
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest 
    environment: 
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3 
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 42181 
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000 
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5 
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2 
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: localhost:22888:23888;localhost:32888:33888;localhost:42888:43888 
    network_mode: "host" 

  kafka-1: 
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest 
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper-1 
      - zookeeper-2 
      - zookeeper-3 
    ports: 
      - "19092" 
    environment: 
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1 
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: localhost:22181,localhost:32181,localhost:42181 
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:19092 
    network_mode: "host" 

  kafka-2: 
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest 
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper-1 
      - zookeeper-2 
      - zookeeper-3 
    ports: 
      - "29092" 
    environment: 
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2 
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: localhost:22181,localhost:32181,localhost:42181 
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092 
    network_mode: "host" 

  kafka-3: 
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest 
    depends_on: 
      - zookeeper-1 
      - zookeeper-2 
      - zookeeper-3 
    ports: 
      - "39092" 
    environment: 
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3 
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: localhost:22181,localhost:32181,localhost:42181 
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:39092 
    network_mode: "host"
```

I have run the following commands:

```
docker-compose up --no-start
docker-compose start zookeeper-1
docker-compose start zookeeper-2
docker-compose start zookeeper-3

docker-compose run -d --service-ports kafka-1
docker-compose run -d --service-ports kafka-2
docker-compose run -d --service-ports kafka-3
```

The zookeeper-1,2,3 started but kafka-1 failed with exit code 0.
When I do `docker-compose start kafka-1`, the ports are not exposed but the service is started.

The output of the above commands:

**docker ps**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7abec60edd7a        confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            kafka-cluster_zookeeper-2_1_c9f58ba3fbc8
68ec403740d6        confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            kafka-cluster_zookeeper-3_1_31e4762a61bb
69d6645487aa        confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest   "/etc/confluent/dock…"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes                            kafka-cluster_zookeeper-1_1_8bbd729b09d8
```

**docker logs of kafka-1, kafka-2, kafka-3 (all are same)**

```
[main-SendThread(localhost:42181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:42181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[main-SendThread(localhost:42181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:42181, initiating session
[main-SendThread(localhost:42181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
[main-SendThread(localhost:32181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:32181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[main-SendThread(localhost:32181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:32181, initiating session
[main-SendThread(localhost:32181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
[main-SendThread(localhost:22181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:22181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[main-SendThread(localhost:22181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:22181, initiating session
[main-SendThread(localhost:22181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x0, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
[main] ERROR io.confluent.admin.utils.ClusterStatus - Timed out waiting for connection to Zookeeper server [localhost:22181,localhost:32181,localhost:42181].
[main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x0 closed
```

**docker-compose ps**

```
                  Name                              Command            State    Ports
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
kafka-cluster_kafka-1_1_c79e5ef5d397       /etc/confluent/docker/run   Exit 0        
kafka-cluster_kafka-2_1_d4399ed0a670       /etc/confluent/docker/run   Exit 0        
kafka-cluster_kafka-3_1_2df6f47759c0       /etc/confluent/docker/run   Exit 0        
kafka-cluster_zookeeper-1_1_8bbd729b09d8   /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up            
kafka-cluster_zookeeper-2_1_c9f58ba3fbc8   /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up            
kafka-cluster_zookeeper-3_1_31e4762a61bb   /etc/confluent/docker/run   Up
```

Comment: what does `docker ps` say?

Comment: what's the output of `docker-compose ps`? and of `docker-compose logs kafka-1` ?

Comment: @freakman I attached the output and logs

Comment: @RobinMoffatt see the edited question.

Comment: which platform you are on mac or linux?

Comment: @Ntwobike linux

Comment: can you remove the ports and try, since you are already using "host" as the network mode you should be able to access the kafka

Comment: @Ntwobike ok, I will try.

Comment: @Ntwobike It did not work. I am trying to access kafka in an outside machine that is not the same as host machine

Comment: Check out the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086884/not-able-consume-messages-from-remote-machine-in-kafka/51098478#51098478 Might help.

Comment: @Bitswazsky Yes, that is the problem, I was writing the answer and you commented it!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that in `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` must be set to the IP address of the host. So that when you run it on another machine, that machine will be able to access the kafka using the IP address.

```
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://10.1.1.1:39092
```

Next point, pointed out by @Ntwobike is to remove the -p option. Not that it is not needed, but it is redundant when the `--net=host` option is set.

**Most important**, is to **check the firewall**. Check the **iptables** rules and change them to `FORWARD ACCEPT` (in my case I have done so,since mine is a development host).

If you are using CentOS or RHEL, you can try stopping the `firewalld` and check to see if it is the firewall that is creating the problem.

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

For others, it is ufw (Ubuntu, Mint)

```
systemctl stop ufw
```

Alternatively, you can also do an `iptables -F` but **before that** make sure that you **backup your iptables rules** using

`iptables-save > /home/iptables_rules_bak`

and then after flushing the rules, you can do

`iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`

Comment: It's not clear why you had to edit the Compose file on Github. It already works for inside and outside the Docker network. https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: @cricket_007 But, somehow it did not work for me! I had to edit the advertised listeners

Comment: Right, you need to edit that anyway, but it doesn't have to be the host IP

Comment: @cricket_007 What else could it be other than the Host IP?

Comment: Whatever externally resolvable address that clients can use to uniquely identify that broker. For example, in AWS (or other clouds), it might be an external IP of the VPC, with the port setup by a target group

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [all-in-one](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5.0.0-post/examples/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml) Compose example by Confluent, then everything is setup correctly for broker access in all directions, and not using `network: host` "hacks" (which only would work on Linux)

Refer

```
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
```

Outside of the Docker network, you can connect via port 29092, but within, it's 9092

---

More importantly, the Zookeeper connection strings should actually point at one another, not `localhost`

I would also like to point out that multiple brokers on one machine doesn't have many benefits, and if you want persistent data (don't lose everything if you restart your computer, or Docker), you'll want volume mounts

Comment: What is meant by pointing out to one another? In KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT? They have mentioned multiple zookeeper nodes there, is that wrong?

Comment: `localhost` means the Kafka container itself, not the Zookeeper container(s) on the Docker network. Even if you set `--net=host` (`network_mode: "host" in Compose), it is still somewhat wrong, and you're making the problem behind poor configuration.